# Android Gallery Selection - URI Path is Invalid

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement multiple image selection from the gallery on Android devices. I'm initiating the dialog as follows:

```
Intent imageChoose = new Intent();
imageChoose.setType("image/*");
imageChoose.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
imageChoose.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(imageChoose, "Select Picture"), 1);
```

When I select one or more images '**onActivityResult**' fires, and the intent data is returned, the uriString is strange. I've attached a comparison between the data's uriString variable from the regular picker intent, versus the multi-select intent. I believe the strange format of the uriString is causing my upload to fail. Any suggestions would be helpful. Let me know if I should post more information.

[image: Normal Picker Intent Data]

[image: Multi-select Picker Intent Data]

Edit:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FILE_ACTION:
                try {
                    if (data != null && data.getData() != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        String path = getRealPathFromUri(this, selectedImageUri);
                        filePickerCallback.onFilePicked(new File(path)); // sends file to upload code
                    }
                    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        filePickerCallback.onCancelled();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error getting file picker result", e);
                    filePickerCallback.onError();
                }
                break;

            case CAMERA_ACTION:
                try {
                    final File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        onComplete = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                f.delete();
                            }
                        };
                        filePickerCallback.onFilePicked(f);
                    }
                    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        f.delete();
                        filePickerCallback.onCancelled();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error getting file picker result", e);
                    filePickerCallback.onError();
                }
                break;

            case MULTI_FILE_SELECT:
                try {
                    if (data != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                        ClipData clips = data.getClipData();

                        if(clips != null) {
                            for(int i = 0; i < clips.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                ClipData.Item item = clips.getItemAt(i);
                                Uri uri = item.getUri();
                                File imageFile = new File(uri.toString());
                                // process each file...
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            // user only selected a single image
                            Uri uri = data.getData();
                            File imageFile = new File(uri.toString());
                            // process single file
                        }

                    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        filePickerCallback.onCancelled();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error getting file picker result", e);
                    filePickerCallback.onError();
                }
                break;

            default:
                Log.w(TAG, "onActivityResult got unknown request code " + requestCode);
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


public static String getRealPathFromUri(Activity activity, Uri contentUri) {
        if (contentUri.getScheme() != null && contentUri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
        else {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                String[] filePathField = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, filePathField, null, null, null);
                if (cursor == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("got null cursor when attempting to find path for external storage uri");
                }

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            finally {
                if (cursor != null) cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want help with your `onActivityResult()` implementation, post your `onActivityResult()` implementation, particularly where you are using `getClipData()` as is described in [the `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE).

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added the code you requested. Really scratching my head here. I appreciate your help greatly. I've left out some code for the sake of brevity.

Comment: When you write "is causing my upload to fail", what do you mean? Are you crashing? If so, where, and what's the stack trace? Also, since your `getRealPathFromUri()` is the same piece of junk that gets copied all over teh Interwebs, you will run into problems, as [a `Uri` is not necessarily a file](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). Use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to access a `content://` `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare the crash occurs during the upload...which is due to the messed up path I'm getting back. As long as I can figure out the path problem the rest should be easy. I'll take your advice and report back shortly. Thanks again.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm able to open an input stream using InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri), but don't understand how to obtain the real path to the file from here. All examples seem to work in reverse...as the user already knows the file name.

Comment: "don't understand how to obtain the real path to the file from here" -- there is no "real path" that you can access. This is covered in [the blog post that I pointed you to in my last comment and am linking to again right here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). Use the `InputStream` to upload the data to your server.

Comment: @CommonsWare Gotcha. In that case it looks like the other picker code is implemented poorly as well.

Comment: @CommonsWare So in this case, how does one obtain the file type and name correctly from the returned intent data?

Comment: For the file type, quoting [the blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html): "Find their MIME type via getType() on ContentResolver". For the name, there really is no name, though you could base on one `DISPLAY_NAME`. Quoting [the blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html): "Find out their DISPLAY_NAME and SIZE — the OpenableColumns — via a query() on the Uri (again, using a ContentResolver, or in theory a CursorLoader)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Uri` value does not have to point to a local file resource that you can read. There are various possible `Uri` schemes, including all the standard Internet ones (e.g., `http`). From the standpoint of content pickers, you will mostly get back `file://` and `content://` schemes, and a *lot* more of the latter over time.

A `Uri` with a `content://` scheme that points to a stream behaves much like a `Uri` with an `http://` scheme. Neither necessarily point to some local file. Instead, you consume the stream itself (`openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` for `content://`, something like `HttpUrlConnection` for `http://`), obtain the MIME type independently (`getType()` on a `ContentResolver` for `content://`, get it from HTTP headers for `http://`), and cook up your own concept for a filename, as there may not be one readily derivable from the `Uri` itself.

> I'd love to dive into the reasoning behind making this so convoluted

`content://` streams exist for much the same reason that `http://` streams exist: inter-process communication. It so happens that most `http://` streams are for transferring data between different computers, but that does not have to be the case.

In the specific case of Android `content://` streams, a given `Uri` *could* point to an ordinary file that *could* be on external storage somewhere that, if you have the appropriate permission, could be read by your app. However, a `content://` stream could be:

- a file on external storage, but you don't have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, or
- a file on internal storage from the app that is responsible for the file (and you don't have access to other apps' internal storage), or
- an encrypted file that needs to be decrypted, or
- an asset, raw resource, ZIP file entry, or something else that needs to be streamed from some other container, or
- a file that exists in "the cloud" that a provider will download to the device when needed, or
- content that is generated on the fly, much how an `http://` stream does not have to represent some physical file on the Web server

And I'm sure there are other scenarios as well that I'm not thinking of off the top of my head.

In short, `content://` is flexible, whereas files are not.

Comment: Your explanation is clear and makes sense. I understand the value from an IPC standpoint, based on reading your blog post. I think it's just frustrating in terms of how we're using it in our particular project...and probably more so since it was written incorrectly from the start. Sigh.

Comment: @lakehousetech: Well, in your defense, Google's only been "beating the drum" about stopping sharing files directly and using `ContentProviders` for the past 18 months or so. As a result, there's a lot of "institutional knowledge" out there that pre-dates this period. However, particularly with the Storage Access Framework in Android 4.4, you will be getting a lot more `content://` `Uri` values, and so there's no really avoiding 'em.

Comment: No worries. I'd rather make the effort and follow best practices, than end up in trouble down the road.